# How to display category image instead of category name in article in joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x

In Joomla 4, what is the code that makes me show the category image in the article?

Previously, I used this code for Joomla 3:

```
<?php
$secid = $this->item->catid;
$category = JCategories::getInstance('Content')->get($secid);
if ($category->getParams()->get('image')): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $category->getParams()->get('image'); ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code does not work in Joomla 4.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that code and it worked ok for me. What are you getting when you examine the element in your browser devtools? And just to check: have you changed where you store your images? And is this on the joomla site front-end, rather than the admin back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in **templates/[your_template]/html/com_content/article/default.php**
Modify the code to your needs.

//retrieve category id
$category = JCategories::getInstance('Content')->get($this->item->catid);

// echo out the category image
echo HTMLHelper::_('image', $category->getParams()->get('image'), $category->getParams()->get('image_alt'));

Tested on Joomla 4.3.4